# How do I completely remove Parallels Desktop from my Mac?

Tags: macos, parallels

Some friend wanted to try to install Windows on my Mac using Parallels Desktop 9. But he failed and left a mess up on my Mac.

How could I totally remove that stuff (the app and the Windows system)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have [knowledgebase articles](http://kb.parallels.com/en/114624) on how to do that.

Comment: I normally don't but since it takes a single google search to find the requested information, I don't see the need to copy the entire page contents here.

Comment: That's total BS, I did what they say and I still see their files all over the place in spotlight, even after reindexing.

Answer (score 0):

[This link gives a breakdown](https://nektony.com/how-to/uninstall-parallels-on-mac), note the background service that may still be running and left over files.